# Why did many simultaneously earn the generalist badge?

Tags: support, badges

It appears that 20 hours ago, [75 people earned the generalist badge](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/badges/15/generalist).  For all who currently have the [generalist](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generalist) badge, it was awarded at this time.

What event or sequence of events caused the simultaneous awarding of the [generalist](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generalist) badge to 75 users?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a requirement that a site must fulfil for Generalist badges to be awarded, namely that the top-40 tags have 201 questions or more ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/255554)). Academia passed this threshold yesterday¹, and hence everyone eligible for this badge² received it at the same time.

---

<sup>¹ with [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/72922/7734) (there are two tags with 201 questions, and this is the most recent one in those tags)

² which were quite a lot by the way; [only a handful of sites on the network have more generalists](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/519933/cross-site-generalist-badge-count).</sup>

Comment: Out of interest, how did you find out about the handful of sites with more generalists? Some ingenious db query (if so, any chance of a link to it?), or extensive trawling?

Comment: @EnergyNumbers: Semi-extensive trawling in circumstances that did not allow me to focus on any intelligent tasks – it’s not that much to do if you know what you are doing.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers There is an ingenious [sede query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/519933/cross-site-generalist-badge-count) for this. The ingenious part was a ready-made [Cross-site query template](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/355774/cross-site-query-template).